# Generate date array with all dates in between week range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to generate a date array for joining purposes, where I have all dates relative to a week range in the second column.

i.e.

```
SELECT 
generate_date_array(date(2021,1,1),date(2021,11,26),INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

Produces
[image]

What I need is a second column, that shows all the dates between each date row.

i.e.

[image]

Since I am ultimately joining this to another table, to see what week a record creation date is in, for this interval, I'm wanting to make this a table with two columns, and a row for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way of doing this - below is just one and to re-use the "code" you already started with

```
select week, week + step as date
from (
  select 
    generate_date_array(date(2021,1,1),date(2021,11,26), interval 6 DAY) weeks
), unnest (weeks) week, unnest([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) step
```

with output

[image]